# redirecting from a general category page to another specific one

Tags: categories, plugin-recommendation, redirect

can anyone tell me what's the best way to redirect a general category page to a specific one?

for example:

```
categoryName1 -> subcategoryName1
              -> subCategoryName2 
              -> subCategoryName3
categoryName2 -> subCategoryName4
```

and when i click in the menu "categoryName1" (but **not** on "categoryName2") i'm redirect automatically into "subcategoryName2".

thanks a lot!

Comment: Luca, I have really problems to understand what you are looking for with your question. Can you add some more example and describe it a bit more? I guess that's why this question has no answers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for some simple redirect solution, in a [previous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8669/how-to-redirect-category-sci-fi-to-category-scifi/8671#8671) the following two were suggested:

1. [Redirection (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)
2. [Simple 301 Redirects (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

With those or a comparable plugin it should be possible that you can add the redirects you need to your site.