# How to? Redirect /category/sci-fi/ to /category/scifi/?

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, redirect, server, htaccess

I changed the wordpress category slug from "sci-fi" to "scifi" a few months back by accident.

How can I redirect

`/category/sci-fi/` to `/category/scifi/`

so that `/category/sci-fi/page/2/`, `/category/sci-fi/page/3/` etc stops resulting in 404 errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Redirection plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

It's a WordPress plugin to manage 301 redirections and keep track of 404 errors without requiring knowledge of Apache .htaccess files
And you can use it for your other question
[How to: 301 Redirect /category/ to /customname/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8665/how-to-301-redirect-category-to-customname)
to.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your reply. I use to use that plugin. Unfortunately the plugin has been broken for many users since wordpress 3.0.3 also see the # of "broken" votes under the "compatibility" section of the url you provided above.  I can't get it to work any more and also was hoping I could just use htaccess rewrite rules since as far as i know to redirect one category renamed should only be one line.

Comment: sorry i use "Simple 301 Redirects" and its working fine on 3.0.4 and 3.1 on my end. but also you can create the simple RewriteRule form what to what

Comment: Yes I've tried that also. I emailed the developer (Scott Nelle) of "Simple 301 redirect" about the the same redirect above. His response:

 --- "Hi Hydn,
I don't have any sort of wildcard functionality built in. I know, it's a bummer. I've got adding wildcards on my list of things to do but I just haven't been able to make time, and I can't predict when I'll be able to get to it." ---

And yes a "RewriteRule form what to what" is the purpose of my question posted here.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok for the record its:

```
RewriteRule ^category/sci-fi/?(.*)$ /category/scifi/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope this helps someone else who's been searching for this also.

Comment: In case you know your domain name, you can spare your server the rewrite rule: `Redirect 301 /category/sci-fi/ http://server/category/scifi/`